# OTA update (Marshmallow) failing with "error" while installing it on a device running Android One

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, ota-update, 6.0-marshmallow, android-one

I live in Australia and during my recent trip to India, I bought an Android One phone called the Lava Pixel v1. The phone is running Android 5.1 and since I have gotten back to Australia, the phone notifies me that I have an update that I need to install. It downloads the 770 mb update and when I try to install it, it shuts down and restarts the phone and then starts installing the update, I can see the Android mascot. After it(the install progress bar) gets to about 20% or so, I just get a message saying "Error" that is all. The Android mascot is lying down or so and from it's open belly there is an exclamation icon ([!have a look at the attached image for what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJPMe.jpg)). At this stage there is no sim card on the phone. Additionally, some apps like Facebook fail to install. Facebook messenger can be installed. I am a developer and I have purchased this phone mostly for dev purposes and would like to get the latest update for my new Android phone, so would appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Whats with the color in the photo.Android gone blue

Comment: I have managed to solve this, have a read of my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer was quite simple, all I had to do was to switch off "Automatic date & time" and "Automatic time zone" in settings and I could install the updates. I no longer "use the network-provided time" or "use network-provided time zone" I am running Marshmallow on my phone right now.

Answer (score 0):

The apps failing to install and the system update failing to install are probably unrelated.

For the most part, the system update is just a big zip file that gets unzipped to a protected part of the storage.  You can't write to the protected part while Android is running.  Unfortunately there are a range of things that can go wrong here, and during the system update the bootloader doesn't have a lot of code.  (We're talking bytes, not megabytes.)  Any descriptive error message it would give would be useless to a user anyway, as you can neither fix the bootloader nor fix the 770 mb update.

I would recommend you contact the manufacturer (or whoever is pushing you the 770 mb update).